# when using a specific database such as sql server,do we have to install and configure odbc?

Tags: sql-server, odbc, protocol-buffers, thrift, avro

when using a specific database such as sql server,do we have to install and configure odbc?

and my other question is why cant thrift/avro/rest/protobuf be used with rdbms,they are services,why are they just used with nosql dbs?
I am reading professional nosql book,and there is a list of different nosql db access methods,and they are listed as nosql db access methods,but when I googled them I saw they are services for serializing datas and so on(each of them is for sth).

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are multiple questions here.

(1) No, SQL Server is accessed best via the SQL Native Client, ADO/MDAC/OLE-DB. Performance-wise ODBC is not recommended at all, although it still may be the most viable option in certain cases.

(2) Thrift is only an RPC-mechanism, which has nothing to do with DB in General. This is a completely different aspect. However, Thrift can of course be used, and in fact it is actually used by the NoSQL database [Apache Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)

I'd recommend to first find out what kind of DB is most suitable for your use case: It may be a typical SQL database, or it may be a classical ISAM or even something like Cassandra, CouchDB or MongoDB. Once you know that, you'll surely find out how to conect with the DB of your choice - or just ask another question :-).